# SAP OpenUI5 - Call function inside attachRequestCompleted

Tags: javascript, callback, sapui5

I have a question about attachRequestCompleted in SAP Open UI5.

My code Looks like this:

```
test : function (oEvent) {
                model = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
                // Load JSON in model
                model.loadData("http://localhost:8080/getJSON");

                model.attachRequestCompleted( function(){
                    console.log(model.getData());
                    this.makeSomething()
                });
        },
```

I want to call my function makeSomething after the model is loaded but it's not possible.

I tried to call it after the function like this. The function gets called but the model isn't loaded.

```
test : function (oEvent) {
                model = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
                // Load JSON in model
                model.loadData("http://localhost:8080/getJSON");

                model.attachRequestCompleted( function(){
                    console.log(model.getData());
                }, this.checkElement());
        },
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **this** keyword in JavaScript is tricky. As W3schools states [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_definition.asp):

> In JavaScript, the thing called this, is the object that "owns" the JavaScript code.
>
> The value of this, when used in a function, is the object that "owns" the function.
>
> The value of this, when used in an object, is the object itself.
>
> The this keyword in an object constructor does not have a value. It is only a substitute for the new object.
>
> The value of this will become the new object when the constructor is used to create an object.

In your case, if you call **this** inside your *test* method, **this** will refer to the current controller. You can use **this** inside your method to access other methods of the controller.

However, if you use **this** inside your callback method, **this** - the owner of the code - is no longer the controller. It is your callback method. *this.makeSomething()* does not exist.

The common way around this is to create a variable usually called **that**, to which you give the value of **this** *while **this** has the value you want to access later on.* You can then access it from your callback method; in the callback method, the **that** variable will not have changed, whereas **this** will be different.

A code sample is worth a thousand words. See my changes below.

```
test : function (oEvent) {
    var that = this;
    model = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
    // Load JSON in model
    model.loadData("http://localhost:8080/getJSON");

    model.attachRequestCompleted( function(){
        console.log(model.getData());
        that.makeSomething();
    });
},
```

When using UI5, I usually create a variable at the same level as my controller methods called **_globalThis**. In the *onInit* method, I then assign it the value of **this** and can then access that same variable from every one of my callback methods.

Comment: Thank you very much for your great answer and explanation! The idea with the var _globalThis is very nice!